# How hosting sites run different node application on same port

Tags: node.js

i am very confuse, when i run node application on a port 80.
Then this port cannot be used again and I accept it is correct.

But i found [runnable](http://runnable.com/) uses port 80 for all its anonymous users.

How it does.(I have no idea about servers and how they work.)

1) Does it uses VM in background.
2) Is it server which do it all (then please tell me how it does)
3) Is it node proxy api which do all work.
4) something else

**codes for nodejs**(update)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(80);
console.log('Server listening on port 80');
```

thanks in advance

Comment: You cannot run two things off the same port...  Unless you use a VirtualServer to run multiple HTTP servers.  The reason ports exist is so run multiple servers of different ports...

Answer (score 1):

Each port is tied to a specific IP address e.g 157.166.226.25:80 is port 80 on cnn.com.  Only one server  on an IP address can listen in on a particular port (otherwise, it would be impossible to determine which server should serve the response).

The workaround for running multiple servers on a single IP address is to point them all at different ports.  HTTP traffic will (usually) come in on port 80 and then the web server can simply redirect the request based on whatever criteria (e.g. domain name) to a different port where the appropriate server is listening.